# How to simplify this c++ code with template?

Tags: c++, templates

This is a simple question, How to make this class simpler?

```
template<typename size_type = uint16_t>
class package
{
public:
    template<typename T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<uint32_t,T>,int>::type = 0>
    package(uint8_t* data,T length) : package(data,(size_type)length)
    {
        std::cout << "uint32_t" << std::endl;
    }
    package(uint8_t* data,size_type length)
    {

    }
}
```

```
template<typename T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<uint32_t,T>,int>::type = 0>
```

Because i don't like this section of code, looks ugly and too long.

Comment: What exactly is ugly? If it seems long, introduce some line breaks. You can also use `std::enable_if_t<...>`, instead of `typename std::enable_if<...>::type>`. Also, you can use `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>` instead of `std::enable_if_t<..., int> = 0`

Comment: no concepts, i am using mingw64

Comment: Since your template is only allowing `uint32_t` it's pretty useless to have a template in the first place. Why not simply `package(uint8_t* data, uint32_t lenght)`?

Comment: the purpose is when the size_type is ```uint32_t```  ,print "uint32_t",other types not print

Comment: @aaaa you can use an if for that

Comment: Sadly "I am using mingw64" is almost meaningless. There are many many different versions of it, and some of them have early support for concepts.

Comment: @user4581301 realy? my version is 8.1 (lastest) ,could you give me an example? so i can try it

Comment: To be honest I couldn't tell you what version of mingw I'm currently running, but the compiler is g++ 8.3 and supports an experimental version of concepts. I could upgrade the compiler to 9.3 in the distribution I'm using (msys2), but to be honest official support starts with GCC10.1, and that's out later this month or early next. But who knows what the schedule looks like right now with all the COVID-19 stuff going on or when it'll make it to mingw.

Comment: This might have potential flaw because overload does not take part in substitution. The second implementation should be a specialization, that can simplify first template

Comment: Could you flesh out your question by adding what your goals are? At the moment, an accurate answer to the literal question is to remove the templated constructor. This both makes your class simpler and eliminates the code you consider to be ugly. It fully addresses the question in its current form, yet I somehow doubt you find it satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what do you mean with "make simpler" but ... what about as follows ?

```
template <typename size_type = std::uint16_t>
struct package
 {
   template <typename T,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::uint32_t, T>
                           || std::is_same_v<size_type, T>, int> = 0>
   package (std::uint8_t *, T)
    {
      if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<std::uint32_t, T> )
         std::cout << "uint32_t" << std::endl;
    }
 };
```

I mean... a template parameter that is SFINAE enabled only when `T` is `std::uint32_t` or `size_type` (that also can be `std::uint32_t`).

> the purpose is when the size_type is uint32_t ,print "uint32_t",other types not print

You can check if `T` is `std::uint32_t` inside the body of the constructor. With `if constexpr`, if you're using C++17 or C++20.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily simplify this at least a little, though it's not drastically shorter.

```
void print(char const *data, uint32_t) { std::cout << data << ", uint32_t\n"; }

template <class T>
void print(char const *data, T length) { std::cout << data << "\n"; }

template <class size_type = uint16_t>
class package
{
public:
    package(char const *data, size_type size) { print(data, size); }
};
```

For the moment, I've changed it to use `char *`, and have both functions do a little printing, so it's easy to test and verify how it's working:

```
int main() {
    package<uint32_t> m("input", 1234);
    package<uint16_t> n("more input", 1234);
}
```

Result:

```
input, uint32_t
more input
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need like this, use a template function `package_print_type` to print the template type, make the template class clear.

```
template<typename size_type>
void package_print_type()
{}

template <>
void package_print_type<uint32_t>()
{
    std::cout << "uint32_t" << std::endl;
}

template<typename size_type = uint16_t>
class package
{
public:
    package(uint8_t* data,size_type length)
    {
         package_print_type<size_type>();

    }
};
```

you can also write the overload function:

```
template<typename size_type>
void package_print_type(size_type l)
{}


void package_print_type(uint32_t l)
{
    std::cout << "uint32_t" << std::endl;
}

template<typename size_type = uint16_t>
class package
{
public:
    package(uint8_t* data,size_type length)
    {
         package_print_type(length);

    }
};
```

I test it in the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/uY6iYc), you can see the result.